# binding working on entry but not on a button

Tags: python, tkinter

My return key binds to 2 different things on my screen, an entry box and a button. When you press return on the entry box(`self.ans`), it works fine and then gets disabled, then another button pops up called `next`(`self.nex`), its meant to go run another method but it doesn't work when i press return. Whats wrong? please help me fix it, thanks.

```
class Question1:
    def __init__ (self, master):
        global answer
        randomiser()
        self.qpicker = [self.__init__, self.q2, self.q3, self.q4]
        self.master = master
        self.user_choice = StringVar()
        self.user_choice.set("")
        self.frame = Frame(master, padx=200, pady=200)
        self.frame.grid()
        self.q = Label(self.frame, text="What is {} + {} ?".format(x, y), pady=20, font="10")
        self.q.grid(row=0)
        self.ans = Entry(self.frame, width=50, textvariable=self.user_choice)
        self.ans.focus_set()
        self.ans.bind("<Return>", self.correct)
        self.ans.grid(row=1)

    def correct(self, event):
        global p
        try:
            if int(self.user_choice.get()) == answer:
                cor = Label(self.frame,text="Your answer is correct!", font="8")
                cor.grid(row=5, pady=20)
                p += 1
                self.sub.destroy()
                self.ans.configure(state="disabled")
                self.nex = Button(self.frame, text="Next",font="10", width=10, command=self.necs)
                self.nex.bind("<Return>", self.necs)
                self.nex.grid(row=4, pady=10)
            else:
                inc = Label(self.frame,text="incorrect, the correct answer is {}".format(answer), font="8")
                inc.grid(row=5, pady=20)
                self.sub.destroy()
                self.ans.configure(state="disabled")
                self.nex = Button(self.frame, text="Next", font="10", width=10, command=self.necs)
                self.nex.bind("<Return>", self.necs)
                self.nex.grid(row=4)

 def necs(self):
        self.frame.destroy()
        random.choice(self.qpicker)(root)
```

Comment: Why on Earth would you abbreviate "next" to "nex"??? :)

Comment: @michalwa i have another variable called next

Comment: But it's evidently not an attribute of your class, so what's the problem with defining `self.next`? I would advise you to name things descriptively and in a readable way, it helps when solving all sorts of issues.

Comment: The button doesn't have keyboard focus, so keyboard events don't go to it.

Comment: @BryanOakley sorry i dont understand what keyboard focus means, mind explaining it a little more? and why would it work for my entry if i did the same thing for both? thanks